# How do I create a Solr user?

Tags: php, solr

I’m trying to set up PHP Solr on my server.

I’ve done this before, and I’ve gotten it almost complete, but my documentation is missing one part, which is how to create a Solr user. I’ve got Tomcat and Solr up and running, my index is created, and I’ve got a web page that tries to connect to the Solr server with the following code:

```
$options = array
(
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'login'    => constant("SOLR_LOGIN"),
'password' => constant("SOLR_PSWD"),
'port'     => '8080',
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);
```

And I have my constants defined in another file that is included. The only part I’m stuck on is where I actually create the user account that uses this login. I’ve tried searching for this in SO and also Yahoo and Google, and nothing comes up that answers my question. The documentation I’ve found just goes over descriptions of the various objects or code, and doesn’t refer to this aspect of the setup. Can anyone tell me which file I should edit for this, and what lines I should add? I’m on a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only part I’m stuck on is where I actually create the user account
>   that uses this login.

If you look at the [`SolrClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/solrclient.construct.php) documentation, there is a big hint (emphasis mine):

> - login           (The username used for **HTTP Authentication**, if any)
> - password        (The **HTTP Authentication** password)

Meaning, there are no users within Solr at all. Authentication is handled on the web server level. Either via a user/password combo set in Tomcat. Or—the way I prefer—via an Apache user/password combo that works by having Apache be a reverse proxy to Tomcat.

Or—as the documentation implies—“The username used for HTTP Authentication, *if any*” meaning you don’t need to have any authentication at all. Which is not advisable for a production environment, but acceptable for closed-network testing.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I recall that I did that last time now. It's just been long enough that I couldn't remember. No wonder I couldn't find anything about creating users for Solr!